# How to put GWT modules in a subdirectory of the WebApp

Tags: gwt, web-applications

For a few weeks I've been trying out GWT. Now I want to integrate a new module i made in GWT with an existing Web application. My problem is that I wan t the module to be put in a subdirectory of the webapp. Currently the code is put in ${webappDirectory}, but I want it in ${webappDirectory}/protected.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

GWT always compiles to a subfolder (named after the compiled module, or its `rename-to` attribute) of the `-war` folder you give it as argument; and it makes no assumption as to where the host page (the page that loads the *.nocache.js file) lives.

That means you can very well have your host page in a `protected` subfolder and have it load `../protected-gwt/protected-gwt.nocache.js`.

If you really do want to put the compiled JS into the `protected` folder you'll have to either use it as the `-war` folder (and pass `-deploy` as argument to the GWT compiler pointing to the parent folder's `WEB-INF/deploy` –or somewhere else– if you don't want a `protected/WEB-INF/deploy` folder to be created), or move the files later, during your build process.
In any case, this will impact your ability to use the DevMode; one simple thing that's assured to work, is to deploy your webapp and launch the DevMode in `-noserver` mode.